# Custom service worker

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm trying to implement a notification system on my website. So I'm trying to register a service worker, and I can't seem to make it work.

I've created a module with the following layout :

default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>

        <script src="[Vendor_Module]::js/main.js"/>

   </head>
</page>
```

And here's how I'm trying to register my worker (I'm following a tutorial from google) :

main.js

```
console.log('hello');
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
    .then(function(swReg) {
      console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

      swRegistration = swReg;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
  }
```

Finally I'm getting this error in the chrome console :

```
main.js:12 Service Worker Error TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mywebsite') with script ('mywebsite/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

I'm guessing I'm not providing the right path for the worker. Given my following directory tree, what filepath should I give to register() ?

```
Vendor/
└── Module/
    ├── etc/
    │   └── module.xml
    ├── view/
    |   └── frontend/
    |       ├── layout/
    |       |   └──default.xml
    |       └── web/
    |           └── js/
    |               ├── main.js
    |               └── sw.js
    └── registration.php
```

UPDATE :

It works when I give 
`/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/fr_FR/Vendor_Module/js/sw.js`
to `register()` but is seems hacky to me ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: registration.php must be on the same level of etc and view

Comment: It is, I made a mistake writing the tree

Comment: 404 means not found. did you double check all file paths and filenames?

Comment: I know 404, the script is in main.js, which is at the same level as ws.js, I shouldn't have to specify any path other than the filename, in a normal configuration. I don't know if that's the case in a magento configuration.

Comment: i think you forogt one big issue: javascript is executed in the clients browser. how is the browser supposed to know the path to the sw.js? you should provide an aboslut path

Comment: Thing is both js files are in pub/static/frontend/vendor_module/js , which is what the browser sees ?

Comment: "mywebsite/static/frontend/vendor_module/js/sw.js"is not the same as "mywebsite/sw.js" how is the browser supposed to know to load it from static/frontend/vendor_module/js

Comment: because that's what the server sends to the browser ? What path do you think I should use ? I tried the absolute path, didn't work.